# How to Read GZIP csv from S3 directly into pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm writing an airflow job to read a gzipped file from s3.

First I get the key for the object, which works fine

```
obj = self.s3_hook.get_key(key, bucket_name=self.s3_bucket)
```

obj looks fine, something like this:

```
path/to/file/data_1.csv.gz
```

Now I want to read the contents into a pandas dataframe. I've tried a number of things but this is my current iteration:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], compression='gzip')
```

This returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 's3.Object' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong? i feel like I need to do something with StringIO or BytesIO...I was able to read it in as bytes, but thought there was a more straight forward way to get to a dataframe

Just in case it matters, one row of the data looks like this when I unzip and open in CSV:

```
 9671211|ddc9979d5ff90a4714fec7290657c90f|2138|2018-01-30 00:00:12|2018-01-30 00:00:16.069048|42b32863522dbe52e963034bb0aa68b6|1909705|8803795|collect|\\N|0||0||0|
```

Answer (score 7):

figured it out:

```
obj = self.s3_hook.get_key(key, bucket_name=self.s3_bucket)
df = pd.read_csv(obj.get()['Body'], compression='gzip', header = None, sep = '|')
```